# Base component in AngularJS 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, custom-component

We're working with components in our newest project.

I'm trying to achieve something like the code below:

```
<custom-form submit-button="true">
    <custom-input-text required="true" maxlength="20"></custom-input-text>
    <custom-input-number required="false" maxlength="6"></custom-input-number>
</custom-form>
```

In my **custom-input-*whatever*** component, I want to inherit validations and other information of a component called **custom-input-base**, because in this base component will be coded the common validations of input forms (like 'maxlength', 'required', etc..), and then add the validations of this specific input text.

Is that possible?

I'm starting with Angular development, then maybe this question is quite simple. Thank you!

Comment: There are many different ways to handle errors in forms: on the client side using html5 validation, on the client side using custom angular validation and showing `span`s or `div`s containing the error message or server side validation. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: I would leverage ngMessages for inline validation. Why reinvent the wheel??